# How can I download and send .exe file in tetelgram bot using an url?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a telegram bot using java .
I want to sent some .**exe** files by **url** and I have already tried the SendDocument class it is not working with different urls maybe telegram SendDocument does not support files with .exe format :

```
SendDocument sender = new SendDocument();
sender.setChatId(chat_id);
sender.setDocument("https://www.psiphon3.com/psiphon3.exe"); // for example

// I have also used the setNewDocument method . no difference !

try {
sendDocument(sender);
} catch (TelegramApiException a) {
e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

the error was :

`Error sending document: [400] Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified`

anybody have any suggestion?
is it possible to convert the .exe to .zip and then send it?

Comment: Please include examples of what you have tried so far and also include any errors you might get.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the Telegram "Send by URL" method does not allow sending executable files.
The documentation says:
“In sendDocument, sending by URL currently only works for gif, pdf, and zip files.”
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files

Use "Sending by file_id", after downloading the file to the Telegram server.